# Why 'click' event not triggering for buttons added dynamically to a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, delegates, click

I'm using [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) for a table populated via Ajax call. Some columns are data from database but in the last column I put some buttons. When I click on that buttons the `click` event is not triggered, why?

I tried to delegate the event but it is triggered first time only (the first button I click, none for following clicks):

```
$( '#my_table' ).DataTable( {
            language: {
                url: 'https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/Italian.json'
            },
            ajax: {
                url: ccwhatsapp_ajax.url + '?action=get_users_for_datatable'
            },
            responsive: true,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            columns: [
                { data: 'full_name' },
                { data: 'login_email' },
                { data: 'phone' },
                { data: 'info' },
                { data: 'actions' }
            ],
            columnDefs: [
                { width: '20%', targets: [0, 1, 2, 3] },
            ]
        } );

$( '#my_table' ).on( 'click', 'tbody tr td button.btn', function () {
                console.log("Click on a button!");
            } );

            $( "#my_table" ).delegate( "tbody tr td button.btn", "click", function() {
                console.log("Click on a button!");
            });

            $( '.btn-primary' ).on( 'click', function () {
                console.log("Click on a button!");
            } );
```

What's wrong?

Comment: for dynamically created buttons you shoud use  $(document).on("click", "#my_table" ...

Comment: It should work as long as you don't destroy the root element you are attaching the event handler to. It is not necessary for the root to be _document_, but better attach to an ascendant of the table. Use the developer console to check if the selector you are using really selects the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the listener to be:

```
$( '#my_table tbody' ).on( 'click', 'tr td button.btn', function () {
            console.log("Click on a button!");
} );
```

There's an example of that on the DataTables website [here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html).

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the div "ancestor / ascendant" of the table:

```
$( '#table_container table' ).on( 'click', 'button.btn', function () {
    console.log($(this));
} );
```